# Substitute everything but letters

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, tr

I am trying to write a single line bash command that will replace every single not letter into a newline. (I am using bash)

Right now, I have this: `tr ^[a-zA-Z]g '\n'`

I have also tried `tr [^a-zA-Z]g '\n'` Both don't work.

I thought that the ^ character would have the regular expression match everything but a-z and A-Z, and thus turn all other characters into newlines, but instead it still jus turns a-z and A-Z into newlines, and keeps the other characters.

How can I make sure that I am using the ^ to reverse the regex, instead of anchor it to the beginning of the line?

Does anyone know the correct syntax? Or should I try using a different command? Thanks.

Comment: You want `^` to be inside `[]`. Outside, it means "beginning of text".

Comment: @Siguza This is not the case for `tr`

Comment: Point taken, although the question is also tagged `sed`, with an emphasis on it in the title...

Comment: @Siguza sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 3):

`tr` does not support regex.

You can use:

```
tr -c 'a-zA-Z' '\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

***sed*** approach(with [***BRE***](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax), *Basic Regular Expression*):

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]/\n/g' testfile
```

Answer (score -1):

Your usage of the `^` character is wrong. The character `^` used outside of square brackets matches the start of a line. When it is used within square brackets, it matches all the characters not contained within the square brackets. So your command should be:

```
tr [^a-zA-Z]g '\n'
```

Follow this link to get a clear idea about how to use the `^` character: [Link to Posix basic matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it still turns the letters into newlines, not the other characters. Do you have any idea why it might do this?